# Requests - POST pagination?

Tags: python, api, pagination, python-requests

i want to get these transactions:
https://www.omniexplorer.info/address/1FoWyxwPXuj4C6abqwhjDWdz6D4PZgYRjA

The first page is no problem with:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

data = [('addr', '1FoWyxwPXuj4C6abqwhjDWdz6D4PZgYRjA')]

response = requests.post('https://api.omniexplorer.info/v1/address/addr/details/', headers=headers, data=data)

response = response.json()

print(response["transactions"])
```

But how can i call page 2 for example?

I tried with params "params  = {'page': 2}" but that doesnt work

Would appreciate any help!

regards

Comment: That depends on the server implementation. See what the browser does when you request the second page in the browser.

Comment: it adds a / with page number - e.g /2 - since i try to get the data through the api, how can that be done with requests?

Comment: Add `/2` to `'https://api.omniexplorer.info/v1/address/addr/details/'`, if that is what the browser does.

Comment: Is there any kind of documentation for the API? If it is a decent API there should be a way to return a count of the total number of records for a request. You should then be able to use this count, along with an 'offset' parameter to page through the records. Sometimes they will even supply a URL in the response which you can just use to request the next set of records.

Comment: thx BigGerman - there is a documentation (https://api.omniexplorer.info/) and the total number of records is available (response["pages"]) - However i havent found a way to set the offset parameter but i will look further, thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the API you're using, you should send the page number as a form value:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "page=19" "https://api.omniexplorer.info/v1/properties/gethistory/3"
```

If you replace page=19 with page=20 you will see that the second call only has three entries, whereas the first has ten.

Using requests, that should be something like this:

```
r = requests.post('https://api.omniexplorer.info/v1/properties/gethistory/3',
                  data={'page': 10})
```

Or, using your own example rather than the one I found on their page:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
}

data = {
    'addr': '1FoWyxwPXuj4C6abqwhjDWdz6D4PZgYRjA',
    'page': 1,
}

response = requests.post('https://api.omniexplorer.info/v1/address/addr/details/',
                         headers=headers, data=data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud think it maybe RESTful,then you will know how to do it

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
pj = {}

for page in range(1,3):
    data = [('addr', '1FoWyxwPXuj4C6abqwhjDWdz6D4PZgYRjA'),('page',page)]
    response = requests.post('https://api.omniexplorer.info/v1/address/addr/details/', headers=headers , data = data)
    response = response.json()
    print(response)
    pj[page] = response["transactions"]
value = list(pj.values())
print(value[0] == value[1])
```

Comment: all in all,it depends on my experience more than try to understand api doc.I did not see any details about how to access next page,in document

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar request to get all companies from an API. In my case would like to get all companies, but the result set with the below query produces the following error.

> error internal_message
> None message
> too many results type
> RESULTLIST_TO_LARGE

Now I am looking into paginating the request, but I cannot find a way to do it. The API documentation is [here](https://www.zefixintg.admin.ch/ZefixPublicREST/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/ZefixPublicREST/v3/api-docs/swagger-config#/)

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from urllib import response
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

def company_load():
  url = 'https://www.zefixintg.admin.ch/ZefixPublicREST/api/v1/company/search'
  
  headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Basic <*password*>'
  }

  payload = json.dumps({
      "activeOnly": True
    })
  
  r= requests.post(url, headers=headers, data= payload)
  response = r.json()
  full_companies= pd.DataFrame(response)
  return full_companies

companies_df= company_load()
```

Answer (score 0):

Improved offered solution on pagination loop.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas import json_normalize

url = 'https://api.omniexplorer.info/v1/address/addr/details/'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

page = 1
data_json = []

while data_json is not None:
    data = [('addr', '1FoWyxwPXuj4C6abqwhjDWdz6D4PZgYRjA'),('page',page)]
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers , data = data)
    data_json = response.json()['transactions']
    print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_json))
    if data_json is None:
        break
    page += 1
```